# "You shouldn't do many things" meaning

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

> You should not do many things.

Which can this sentence above mean?

> "There are a lot of things you shouldn't do."

or

> "It's not good if you do many things."

I am not sure if I can say it like this:

> "You should not do many things before going to bed: eat a lot, use smartphones, exercise too hard, watch TV and so on."

> "You should not do all these things at one time. You will damage your health."

Comment: Where did you read this sentence? Without context, it's impossible to say for certain what is meant.

Comment: @KateBunting Thank you, I myself  made this sentence.  So, can it mean both of them??

Comment: Well, the second meaning would be better expressed as "You shouldn't _try to_ do [too] many things at once."

Comment: @KateBunting Oh, I see!  Thank you very much!  Might it be rarely said "You should not do many things" in the second meaning?

Comment: I would think it very unlikely that anyone would use those words to express that meaning.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The first meaning/interpretation you gave is correct. The second is wrong, we do not know by the current sentence whether `"shouldn't"="not good"`, and is therefore ambiguous. "good" can be applied differently in different sentences, depending on the perspective and context, so it's not a good idea to use that interpretation. And yes your examples seem fine.